# Clean unwanted files after an incomplete download, Ubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: installation, apt, eclipse

I am currently working on getting eclipse installed on Ubuntu 12.04.2 on a live USB of 4GB with 3000MB as persistence. I used some commands like:

```
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade
    $ sudo apt-get install cmake
    $ sudo apt-get install iibgtk2.0-dev
    $ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D mAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ./
    $ make

    $ sudo apt-get install eclipse
    $ sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse eclipse-cdt
```

when I was in the process of completing "sudo apt-get install eclipse", some error due to bad internet connection at that particular time and i had to stop the downloading and installing progress of eclipse and I think it must have used some big amount of my usb storage because, now when i try again it with stable internet connection, it is showing some error with "No disk space" and recommends me "sudo apt-get update/upgrade" and doing the same is also of no help. 
Can someone please tell me a effective way of removing junk files like the one i mentioned above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to execute these commands. They will help to clear/fix broken packages and also try to install required library packages needed to run packages efficiently:

1. Fix using Command Line:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get --purge remove
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo apt-get clean
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
2. Fix using `Synaptic Package Manager`:

   - Fist install synaptic package manager if you don't have already installed:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install synaptic
     ```
   - Then open synaptic package manager -> click **Custom Filters** down-left -> click **Broken** top-left, it will list all broken packages try to all broken packages. Also if any residual packages are there on more option you will get as **residual packages**.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I needed to kill other apt processes, and then the above commands worked as expected (Ref: Response by cortman in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1911838)

Comment: @HammanSamuel: sounds good.. :)